# Unable to iterate the tree with all the children C#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, treenode

I am trying to call a function after a button click only if any of the node is selected. The `foreach` loop is iterating only the root node avoiding all the children. Note that I have to call this within the button click function. So it will be great if I get both the answers (writing a separate function and calling it in button_click function or directly writing  in the button_click function ).
The `ReadData` function is running fine. Only issue is no iteration of all nodes.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 t = new Form2();           
    TreeNodeCollection node = this.treeView1.Nodes;
    foreach(TreeNode tn in node)
    {
        if(tn.IsSelected)
        {
           //This is the function I need to call from form2.  
           t.ReadData(null);
        }
    }
    t.Show();
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not using the `SelectedNode` property?

Answer (score 1):

You should use recursion to iterate through all nodes:

```
private void ReadRecurcive(TreeNodeCollection nodes, Form form)
{
    foreach (TreeNode tn in nodes)
    {
        if(tn.IsSelected)
        {
           //This is the function you need to call from form2.  
           form.ReadData(null);
        }

        ReadRecurcive(tn.Nodes, form);
    }
}
```

And your handler:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 t = new Form2();           
    TreeNodeCollection node = this.treeView1.Nodes;

    ReadRecurcive(node, t);

    t.Show();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use recursion to achieve this. Check it out on: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwc698z7(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.